# Save POST data To MongoDB: Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, http-post

I'am new with node.js.I Need to save data from HTML page use - form (user name, password, email e.t.c)in Mongodb. I have this code:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id    : String,
      name: String,
      age   : Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);

    app.post('/new', function(req, res){
      new user({
        _id    : req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        age   : req.body.age        
      }).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.send('Successfully inserted!');
      });
    });

<form action="/new" method="POST">
<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="email" /><br />
<label for="name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<label for="age">Age: </label>
<input type="number" name="age" /><br />
<input type="submit"/>
```

When I run server. Trying to save some data. I see message 
"Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"
Somebody help me please with this misunderstood. Thans a lot!

Comment: You have to include the bodyParser middleware to use `req.body`

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Thank you very much! It's works now! I was installing framework - express.  "json" was by default in this line   "app.use(bodyParser.json());"

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't need to define _id in your schema, it gets automatically created.  Maybe you meant to define email : String so it matches your req.body.email

Comment: This is was just example, how create user registration in db.  Where every email unique. I changed this parameter. Now it's working. Thank you.